# Comparing a text file content to folder content via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am a bit new to powershell, so I am trying to create a powershell where it compares a text file content to a content folder. There over 2000 files in folder. I am wondering if my text file is confusing the search because of the numbers before it such as 1. or the url under it? Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks! Example:

```
Text file test.txt
Content: 
1. Hello.mp3
URL
2. Test.mp3
URL
3. Over.mp3
URL

Folder content:
Hello.mp3
Test.mp3
Over.mp3
Stack.mp3

$strReference = Get-Content "C:\Users\User\Downloads\test.txt"
$strDifference = get-childitem -recurse *.mp3
Compare-Object $strReference $strDifference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably got 2 problems. One is a mismatch in data type.

`$strdifference` won't be just strings - it will be a collection of *file system objects* that contain the file name, yes, but also extra attributes on each object.

`$strReference` will be an array of strings, per your variable name.

So what you need to do is manipulate your input data or what you pass to `Compare-Object` so you are comparing strings with strings.

You can use `$strdifference | get-member` to see what properties each item in the list has. They'll be listed as `Note-Property`'. I'm pretty sure `Name` will be one of them.

Then in `Compare-Object`, you've got the `-Property` switch. Now, you might think adding `-Property Name` will solve all your problems, but if you do `$strreference | get-member`, you'll find it *doesn't* have a `Name` property. So that won't work.

So you need to either get the bare file names out of `$strdifference` so it's just a collection of strings or convert `$strreference` into a collection of objects with a `Name` property.

The first option is probably the easiest one.

Also, it'll help with your second problem, which isn't the actual problem, but it's messy - all the extra data you've got in your `$strReference`. So you probably want to import it without the extra stuff:

```
$strReference = Get-Content "C:\Users\User\Downloads\test.txt" | where {$_ -like "*.mp3"}
```

(I haven't tested this - you may need a `-Match` instead. In fact, it might be preferable, it's often more efficient - `-Match 'mp3$'` (`$` means end-of-line in a match).)

And you can do something similar for `$strdifference`, but there you want to `Select`  and expand the Name property, so that it's just a string, not the file object.